# Arrow notation for distinguishing injective non-surjective from non-injective non-surjective functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

In the [definition of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition), the explicit declaration of domain and of codomain in relation to each other is nicely accomplished by the [arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Arrow_notation); e.g. considering the real tangent function:

$$\text{Tan}_{(\text{full})} : \mathbb R \setminus \left\{ \frac{(2 \, k + 1) \, \pi}{2} \, | \, k \in \mathbb Z \right\} \longrightarrow \mathbb R,$$

which, being more specificly a [surjective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#Definition) (i.e. with its image being the entire codomain) can more specificly be denoted as

$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{Tan}_{(\text{full})} : \mathbb R \setminus \left\{ \frac{(2 \, k + 1) \, \pi}{2} \, | \, k \in \mathbb Z \right\} \twoheadrightarrow  \mathbb R; \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad(\text{surj-non-inj})$

or for bijections (surjective as well as [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), i.e. one-to-one function) specificly

$ \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{Tan}^{(\text{bij})}_{(\text{branch})} : (0 ... \pi / 2) \longleftrightarrow \mathbb R_+. \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (\text{surj-inj})$

However, of course we may also consider and purposefully declare functional relations (necessarily with explicitly specified domain and codomain) which are **not surjective**, e.g. the injective function:

$\quad \quad \quad \text{Tan}^{(\text{non-surj})}_{(\text{branch})} \quad \text{ again with domain } (0 ... \pi / 2) \quad \text{ but codomain } \mathbb R, \quad \quad (\text{inj-non-surj})$

or the non-injective function:

$\text{Tan}^{(\text{non-surj})}_{(\text{full})} \text{ again with domain } \mathbb R \setminus \left\{ \frac{(2 \, k + 1) \, \pi}{2} \, | \, k \in \mathbb Z \right\} \text{but codomain } \mathbb C. \quad (\text{non-inj-non-surj}).$

**My question:**

Are there specific distinct arrow symbols known to have been used for expressing e.g. the function declarations $(\text{inj-non-surj})$ and $(\text{non-inj-non-surj})$ explicitly and distinctly in arrow notation ?

Comment: I prefer the notation described by John Bentin here (also see comment by stranger): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/46685

Comment: Maybe ever clearer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4219073

Comment: @311411: _"notation described by John Bentin"_ -- I appreciate this as an answer to my OP question. (But: I totally dislike $\rightarrowtail$ for injection. The tail itself, $\righttail$, looks like there are two (or several) distinct elements of the domain mapped to the same value. And: What I'm trying to get at with my next question is notation for relations which are **not functions** at all, but "one-to-many". Say, like $\leftbroom$, but with arrows. Or $\curlyveeuparrow$", but sideways ...)