# What does the notation $\twoheadrightarrow$ mean?

Tags: notation

I don't know what this double-arrow $\twoheadrightarrow$ means!

Comment: sometimes it means surjective

Comment: It largely depends on the context and the author. I've seen it used for several things, but most often to denote a surjective mapping.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Wikipedia: [Surjective funtion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function)

> A surjective function is a function whose image is equal to its codomain. Equivalently, a function f with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$ is surjective if for every $y$ in $Y$ there exists at least one $x$ in $X$ with $f(x)=y$. **Surjections are sometimes denoted by a two-headed rightwards arrow,** as in $f : X \twoheadrightarrow Y,\;$ [Boldface mine.]

See also the section on the properties or characterizations of ["surjections"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#Properties).

Comment: Time for a nice answer badge! +1

Answer (score 11):

This is usually used in category theory to denote an [epimorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism).

Related question:
[Special arrows for notation of morphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20015/special-arrows-for-notation-of-morphisms)