# What is this symbol: $\mapsto$?

Tags: notation, reference-works

Back in the old days, I had a book that listed many things about math tables and symbols.  What is the modern equivalent book?

My question was unclear.  I think it was because I used one question in the title and another in the body of the post.  Leave it closed.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  `$\mapsto$` produces $\mapsto$, as in $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f:x\mapsto x^3$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner as far as I am aware, the arrow $\to$ is for the mapping between domain and codomain, where as the arrow $\mapsto$ is for the mapping between input and output.

Comment: @MrPie:  isn't that consistent with my example?

Comment: In the function notation, like $f:A\mapsto B$, I know it to represent an injective mapping. This is how my professor taught and Ive seen it in multiple books and a couple of papers, though I dont personally use the notation.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum:  isn't that $\Large\hookrightarrow$?  cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46678/what-are-usual-notations-for-surjective-injective-and-bijective-functions)

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that I was asking for a modern equivalent book, not the modern equivalent of the symbol.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner -- My guess is he might be thinking of $↣$, which I recall being used in my category theory class a lot to represent monomorphisms (which are injections in the category of sets). Though looking it up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20015/special-arrows-for-notation-of-morphisms), it appears that symbol has other uses, maybe? I'm not versed enough in category theory to properly say for sure though. Just a thought (and sorry for assuming if I'm wrong, CogitoErgoCogitoSum).

Comment: @GeoGraphy:  in "modern" times, you can look up symbols on line (e.g., [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)), rather than in a book

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I didn't see the last part of your comment, sorry :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This symbol has no "modern equivalent," to my understanding, because it is still in use today.

$x \mapsto y$ means, for an implied function $f$, that $f$ maps $x$ to $y$, i.e. $f(x)=y$. You might have each side of the arrow written in a general form, such as $x \mapsto x^2$ denoting $f(x)=x^2$, or to denote a particular mapping of elements, such as $2 \mapsto 4$ as under the previous example.

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked the difference tween the symbol ↦ and the symbol →.

Comment: $\to$ usually is used in the definition of the function itself. $f : A \to B$ would be such an example case, where this usage means $A$ is the domain of the function $f$, and $B$ is the codomain of the function. So in that sense, the difference is -- $\mapsto$ is usually used to specify the definition of the mapping itself (i.e. how are elements mapped to each other), while $\to$ is more concerned with the general definition (i.e. which sets are mapped into each other).